# Adicionar campos no FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, campos

Boa noite! Estou querendo desenvolver um gerenciador de tarefas para funcionários de um escritório. Vi alguns vídeos sobre o FullCalendar e vi que no padrão ele aceita os seguintes campos: ID, Title, Start, End e Color. Eu gostaria de que, além desses eventos, fossem acrescentados ainda os Campos: Nome_Funcionario, Nome_Cliente e Observacoes. É possível? Outra dúvida que tenho é a possibilidade de inserir de forma separada data e hora para início e fim, teria como?

Answer (score -2):

Sim, é possivel, basta adicionar no ebjeto Json event as propiedades desejadas, segue um exemplo:

```js
events: [{
              id: 1,
              title: 'Evento do Leonardo',
              start: dataInicio,
              end: dataFim,
              color: '0c4873',
              nomeFuncionario: 'LEONARDO',
              nomeCliente: 'GUSTAVO', 
              url: 'http://localhost:8080/leonardo'
         }]
```

E para recurar esses atributos você deve acessar as 'extendedProps'

```js
let nomeCliente = event.extendsProps.nomeCliente;
```